# Moroccan License Plate Recognition (LPR) using OPENALPR, OpenCV and Tesseract

Tags: python, c++, opencv, python-tesseract, openalpr

I work currently on my project of end of study: the title of my project is "the detection in real time of the Moroccan license plates of vehicles ( ALPR )", I tried to post this my issue    in group ALPR unfortunately ,i received no reply .  i decide to contact you when i see your video in youtube,I want to inform you that I have many problem with Moroccan license plates.
this is an example of Moroccan license plates: 
[Morrocan alpr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXc9C.jpg)

i tried to use [OPENALPR](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr) :
When I run the command line " alpr lprmr.jpg" it
give me this result :

plate0: 8 results
- 4316 confidence: 83.3094 
- 43I6 confidence: 76.1957 
- 431B confidence: 68.5094 
- 431G confidence: 67.8764 
- 431S confidence: 64.9272 
- 43IB confidence: 61.3957 
- 43IG confidence: 60.7626 
- 43IS confidence: 57.8135

Like you see tesseract  fail because of the vertical lines and Arabic characters. However, i can use OpenCV's connected components functions to split the image into 3 sections. The first and third sections will work fine with tesseract. For the Arabic characters, i can build a neural network to classify them if you've enough dataset. To get the full number plate, and I will  have to concatenate the 3 sections. 
for do that i think i should modify the code : **/openalpr/src/openalpr/ocr/segmentation/charactersegmenter.cpp**

**The Question is how can be  modify this code and detect the full Moroccan Plate ??**

Edit: The Arabic letters we use in Morocco are : أ ب ت ج ح د هـ The expected result is : 77143 د  6 دThe vertical lines are irrelevant, I have to use them to separate the image and read data separately.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: There are a lot of flags to add to alpr, country flag for example.

Comment: what do you mean by flag  :

Comment: like this command line : alpr -c us image.jpg

Comment: Look at the documentaion of the alpr for more options, and yes -c is one of them.

Comment: yes , used already :  ./alpr  -c us -p mr --config openalpr.conf.defaults images.jpg --debug it give me the same result , i think the problem is about segmentation.

Comment: I don't think `-c us` is correct for Moroccan plates?

Comment: i tried all country i used ** -c eu us br au ...** , the us and  eu is closer of morrocan plate.

Comment: I have work on the same project, and trust me , moroccan plate aren't easy , morocco plate have several form (rectangles , square,...) And colors , and specifications , you cannot do that with tessrcat or any pretrained model, you need to train your own model and you need to find alot of data ( which is illegal by moroccan authority)